# When I use a dynamic class for my WebService arguments, the public properties are not included

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, web-services, class, actionscript

I have a dynamic Class that is a Value Object that is used to pass arguments to a WebService. It has two public properties:

```
package
{
    [Bindable]
    public dynamic class WebServiceCriteria
    {
        public var property1:String;

        public var property2:String;
    }
}
```

I set these two properties in one part of my application:

```
var myCriteria:WebServiceCriteria = new WebServiceCriteria();

myCriteria.property1 = "x";

myCriteria.property2 = "y";
```

Then I added other - dynamic - properties at another point in my application:

```
myCriteria.property3 = "z";
```

However, when I pass the instance to the WebService as the arguments, the original two public properties are not sent (as I can see in Fiddler), even though they have values. But, I can see them as properties of my Class instance in the debugger just prior to the send().

```
operation.arguments = {args: myCriteria};

operation.send(); // only property3 is sent
```

Why are those two properties not sent?

Here is an example of the SOAP request sent to the WebService:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <intf:webservice_controller xmlns:intf="http://childDir.parentDir">
      <args xsi:type="apachesoap:Map" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap">
        <item>
          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">property1</key>
          <value xsi:type="xsd:string"></value>
        </item>
        <item>
          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">property2</key>
          <value xsi:type="xsd:string"></value>
        </item>
        <item>
          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">property3</key>
          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">z</value>
        </item>
      </args>
    </intf:webservice_controller>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: what happens if you add a forth property, does only 4 get sent, or do 3 and 4 get sent?

Comment: Yes. This is a very simplified version of what I'm actually doing. When I add the "dynamic" properties, I am adding any number of properties, and they ALL get sent without a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is documented in Flex 3.0 manuals. See [Dynamic Classes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_10.html) for more information. A direct quote:

> [...]Methods created in this way, however, do not have access to any private properties or methods of the [example] class. Moreover, even references to public properties or methods of the [example] class must be qualified with either the this keyword or the class name.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your constructor :

```
package
{
    [Bindable]
    public dynamic class WebServiceCriteria
    {
        public var property1:String;
        public var property2:String;

        function WebServiceCriteria()
        {
             prototype.property1 = null;
             prototype.property2 = null;
        }
    }
}
```

... As it seems like only the `Object`s properties are enumerable

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you will be able to send an object to a webservice. If you want to send an object you will need to use remote object. To use a webservice you would need to make your object into some kind of xml or soap request. like

`var myCriteria:WebServiceCriteria = new WebServiceCriteria();`

myCriteria.property1 = "x";

myCriteria.property2 = "y";

operation.send(<request>
                    <property1>{myCriteria.property1}</property1>
                    <property2>{myCriteria.property2}</property2>
                 </request>);

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_intro_2.html

Comment: Really? I've done it this way many times. Flex converts it to an associative array in the SOAP request without a problem, and my CFC accepts it as a struct (see example above).